# C# Selenium xpath cannot find the inner div node

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I tried to access the second inner div node. Here is the structure:

```
<div class = "bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd bDetailBlock secondaryPalette" id="ep">
    <div class ="pbHeader"></div>
    <div class ="pbBody"></div>
```

Through ChroPath add on, with the below xpath it can match the 
 "pbHeader" class

`"html/body/div[4]/div[1]"` 
While trying with the same logic to access the pbBody class it is not pointed to that div node.

`"html/body/div[4]/div[2]"`

I have to access the element inside *pbBody div class*.

Comment: could you share entire snippet of HTML.

Comment: The snippet I provided is deep in html - is there a fast way to grab the entire structure?

Answer (score 1):

For something simple like this, you should use CSS selectors.

```
#ep > div.pbHeader
#ep > div.pbBody
```

If you've omitted some HTML in your question, you might need to remove the `>` indicating child, e.g.

```
#ep div.pbHeader
#ep div.pbBody
```

But... if you must use XPath, you can use the below

```
//[@id='ep']/div[@class='pbBody']
```

Comment: Generally, if you're trying to find a bug in your code, having someone on the sidelines telling you to rewrite the thing in a different programming language is just an unwanted distraction. Switching technologies every time you hit a minor obstacle is not a good way to make progress.

Comment: @MichaelKay Selenium has many locator types available. Switching from XPath to CSS selectors is not a different programming language nor a different technology. There are a number of reasons not to use XPath but I won't go into all that here. You can google, if you are interested.

Comment: @MichaelKay ...but I take your point. I've added an XPath example, if you want to provide some feedback since you are an actual XPath expert. :)

Comment: I'm not saying that using CSS rather than XPath is the wrong approach (on the contrary, CSS was designed for HTML and XPath wasn't); just that I don't think you should make decisions like that in response to this kind of problem. (I can't help debug the XPath here because we don't know enough about the HTML.)

Comment: @MichaelKay I don't completely disagree with you but most of the people asking questions on this tag are very new. For some reason they start with XPath, probably because they can copy them from the browser. Then when they don't work, they can't figure out how to fix them. CSS selectors are faster, better supported in browsers, and, I think, easier to learn than the complex (but powerful) syntax of XPath. Most people don't have hard requirements to use XPath so I generally try to steer them away from XPath.

Comment: Certainly agree with you that people trying to write XPath expressions with no attempt to learn the syntax or semantics of the language except by looking at examples is a major plague.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *absolute xpath* you should use *relative xpath* as follows:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd bDetailBlock secondaryPalette' and @id='ep']//div[@class='pbBody']"));
```

Comment: checking classes when your element relies on `@id='ep'` is redundant. Also you are making a lot of assumptions here: what if classes are not always int he same order? what if `ep` is not static id?